# An interesting pattern in solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

OK, watch this:

Suppose I have a weight on the end of a spring. Assuming the spring obeys Hooke's law, as the weight is displaced from its rest position, the spring exerts a restoring force in the opposite direction who's magnitude is equal to the displacement multiplied by the spring constant.

Suppose that $f(t)$ represents the displacement of the weight at time $t$. If we assume that the spring constant and the mass of the weight are both unity, we have

$$f''(t) = -f(t)$$

This is an equation involving both $f$ itself and its derivative $f''$, so this is presumably a "differential equation". I don't know how to deal with such a thing. But it is clear that this does not yet tell me what $f$ **is**, only that it must satisfy a specific property.

Thinking about this for a moment, it is clear that $f(x) = 0$ has the requested property. This corresponds to the weight remaining stationary for all eternity - a physically valid, but rather "boring" result.

Contemplating this further, it occurs to me that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$, and the derivative of $\cos$ is $-\sin$. So if $f(t)=\sin(t)$ then $f''(t)=-\sin(t)$, which satisfies the equation. By nearly identical reasoning, $f(t)=\cos(t)$ would also work. In short, if you ping the weight, it oscillates around zero.

Now suppose that, by some bizarre mechanism, the restoring force were to somehow be in *the same direction* as the displacement. Impossible, I know. But imagine. Now our equation becomes

$$f''(t)=f(t)$$

Again $f(t)=0$ would work. But what else? Well, there is exactly one function who's derivative equals itself: $\exp$. This is a stronger property than we need, but still, if $f(t)=\exp(t)$ then *every* derivative of $f$ (including $f''$) would equal $f$. This describes the weight accelerating away exponentially - rather as you might expect.

So far, we have two equations. The solution to one is $\sin$. The solution to the other is $\exp$. Two similar equations, two totally different solutions. Or at least, they *look* different. But now I'm thinking about something Euler once wrote:

$$\exp(ix) = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$$

Say that, and suddenly these solutions don't look so dissimilar at all. Now they suddenly look suspiciously similar!

**My question:** Is this the result of some deep and meaningful connection? Or is it merely a coincidence?

---

Holy smokes, you guys are right!

I know, of course, of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$. (For real numbers, they look utterly unrelated. But in the complex plane, one is a trivially rotated version of the other.) What I didn't know, until I looked it up, was the derivatives of these functions.

Since they're defined in terms of $\exp$, I was expecting some really complicated derivative. However, what I actually found (as you presumably all know) is that $\sinh'=\cosh$ and, unlike in the circular case, $\cosh'=\sinh$!

So yes, for $f''=-f$ we have $f=\sin$ or $f=\cos$, and for $f''=f$ we have $f=\sinh$ or $f=\cosh$. So flipping the sign of the differential equation rotates the function in the complex plane. Physically, it doesn't look very meaningful to talk about complex-valued seconds, but mathematically it all looks *vastly* too perfect to be mere coincidence.

Comment: Nice observation. You will be interested in the functions $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$, which are the analogues (for the second problem) of the familiar $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great observation! Yes, this is a very meaningful connection. Let me introduce a bit of notation which I hope will be suggestive. Instead of $f'(t)$, write $D f$. The symbol $D$ here is a *differential operator*: it takes as input a function and returns its derivative. So we can write your two differential equations as
$$(D^2 + 1) f = 0$$

and
$$(D^2 - 1) f = 0.$$

The reason for introducing differential operators is that they can be manipulated like numbers (more formally, they form a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics))): you can add and multiply them ($D^2$ corresponds to taking the derivative twice), and in particular you can *factor* the above differential operators, getting
$$(D + i)(D - i) f = 0$$

and
$$(D + 1)(D - 1) f = 0.$$

This makes it clear that any solution to $(D \pm i) f = 0$ is a solution to the first equation and any solution to $(D \pm 1) f = 0$ is a solution to the second equation. But these first-order differential equations can be solved just by dividing by $f$ and integrating, and we get
$$f = e^{\pm ix}$$

for the first equation and
$$f = e^{\pm x}$$

for the second equation.

**Exercise:** Generalize to the differential equation
$$p(D) f = 0$$

where $p$ is a polynomial.

(If you're wondering how to get the decomposition into sine and cosine, resp. hyperbolic sine and cosine, the abstract answer is that these correspond to different particularly nice behaviors a function can have under the symmetry $f(x) \mapsto f(-x)$; in other words, sine resp. hyperbolic sine corresponds to odd solutions and cosine resp. hyperbolic cosine corresponds to even solutions.)

There are some other abstractions relevant here: $D$ acts on the solutions to the differential equation $p(D) f = 0$ for any polynomial $p$, and the particularly nice solutions we wrote down above are its [eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors). To get all solutions in general, however, we may need to use [generalized eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector).

Comment: I think in order to really comprehend this, I need to go reaquaint myself with the exact properties of the derivatives of sums and products... I want to figure out _exactly_ what solutions these differential equations have. (It looks, for example, like $f=\sin+\cos$ ought to work, but I haven't checked yet.)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: the space of solutions in both cases above is a vector space of dimension $2$ (because taking the derivative is linear and a solution is uniquely determined by $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$) and the solutions I wrote down form a basis. So the general solution of the first one is $A e^{ix} + B e^{-ix}$ (equivalently, $A \cos x + B \sin x$) and the general solution of the second one is $A e^x + B e^{-x}$.

Comment: Like I said, I need to go away and _think_ about this for a while. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Continuing on Qiaochu Yuan's path, from $p(D)f=0$ you might think that there are as many solutions as the degree of $p$, just like there are the same number of roots of a polynomial as its degree.  This is correct.

Your equations are linear, which means that no powers of $f$ appear (though powers of $D$ and the independent variable can occur) and homogeneous (which means there is no constant term).  You can then prove that any linear combination of solutions is again a solution.  So having found that $\exp(t)$ and $\exp(-t)$ are solutions of $f''(t)=f(t)$ you know that $A\exp(t)+B\exp(-t)$ is again a solution for any real $A,B$.  The fact that you have found two and the degree of $D^2-1$ is $2$ means you have found them all.  For $(D^2+1)f=0$ you noted that $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are solutions and Qiaochu Yuan noted that $exp (it)$ and $\exp (-it)$ are solutions, but $\cos t=\frac {exp (it) +\exp (-it)}2$ and $\sin t=\frac {exp (it) -\exp (-it)}{2i}$ so these are linear combinations of each other.

Comment: But this is somewhat subtle if $p$ has repeated roots.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan:  True.  As I understand it, you still have that many solutions and they still form a vector space.  They just look a bit different, like $t \exp(at)$

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha claims that $f''=f$ has the solution $f(t) = A \exp(t) + B \exp(-t)$. I notice that both $\exp(t)$, $\cosh(t)$ and $\sinh(t)$ can be constructed by setting $A$ and $B$ appropriately...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid:  Exactly.  You have a two dimensional vector space of solutions and have found a basis.